# sparse circulant construction python

Tags: python, sparse-matrix

`scipy.linalg.circulant` provides a nice way of turning a (1-D) `numpy` array `x` into a circulant matrix `C`. Is there any stock way of doing so that preserves sparse representation if `x` is a `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` matrix?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create sparse circulant matrix in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39597649/create-sparse-circulant-matrix-in-python)