# How to make the operation != in cvxpy?

Tags: python, cvxpy

I am currently working on `cvxpy` and I have the following constraint:

```
constraints.append(z[p][offices.index(office), offices.index(linked_office)]  != 3/M)
```

I need each value of z to belong to [0,3/M[ U ]3/M,1], how can I proceed ?

Here is the definition of my variable z, with e a matrix n*p which take values between 0 and M-1

```
    z = [] 
    for p in range(P):
        z.append(cp.Variable((n, n)))

    for p in range(P):
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(n):
                constraints.append(z[p][i, j] >= 0)

    for p in range(P):
        for office in offices:
            for linked_office in linked_offices[office]:
                constraints.append(z[p][offices.index(office), offices.index(linked_office)]
                                   <= e[offices.index(office), p] / M)
                constraints.append(z[p][offices.index(office), offices.index(linked_office)]
                                   <= e[offices.index(linked_office), p] / M)
                constraints.append(z[p][offices.index(office), offices.index(linked_office)]
                                   >= e[offices.index(office), p] / M + e[offices.index(linked_office), p] / M - 1)
```

Answer (score -1):

[CVXPY doesn't explicitly allow for not equal to constraints](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/intro/index.html#constraints), and instead the (simple) constraints it allows are `==`, `>=` and `<=`, but that's okay! It just means you instead need to get a little tricky with how you formulate the problem.

For ease of notation, let's say we want to ensure that some value `x` is not equal to some value, N, say. In this case we can write our constraint of `x != N` as follows

```py
eps = 1e-3 # may need to be tuned to your problem's precision
constraint = abs(x - N) >= eps
```

Where this will work if `N` is either an integer, or a floating point value.

So, for your problem you would need to modify your code to something like

```py
# Will depend on the precision of your problem and the value of 3/M
# if you're using big M notation, I imagine 3/M is a very small float 
# and you may need to adjust eps
eps = 1e-3
constraint = abs(z[p][offices.index(office), offices.index(linked_office)] - 3/M) >= eps
constraints.append(constraint)
```

However, for more efficient constraint formulations for CVXPY, [you may find this thread to be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66849908/cvxpy-constraints-formulation)

Comment: Thank you for your answer it's a good idea ! But when I try this method, cvxpy seems not appreciating it and returns me  : " vxpy.error.DCPError: Problem does not follow DCP rules. Specifically:
The following constraints are not DCP:
0.1 <= abs(var17015[0, 3] + -0.5) , because the following subexpressions are not:
|--  0.1 <= abs(var17015[0, 3] + -0.5) ...". Do you know what is the issue ? I don't see why it violates the DCP.

Comment: It may be possible that it is expecting `cvxpy.abs` instead of `abs` .

Comment: Depending on if you're maximizing or minimizing as well, absolute value is convex, which means the DCP rules will require that expression needs to be part of a minimization. If you're maximizing, you may need to multiply the expression by `-1` such that the expression becomes concave. [You may find this page helpful](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/dcp/index.html#dcp-problems)

Comment: You can't just write ``abs(x)>=eps``, this is not convex. You would have to introduce a mixed-integer model for the disjunction ``x<=-eps OR x>=eps`` with all the bells and whistles of mixed-integer optimization. Generally it is a numerically horrible idea to try to have a constraint ``x!=y`` in an otherwise convex problem. For integer variables it makes sense, but for a continuous variable will you say a solution where ``x-y=1e-20`` satisfies ``x!=y`` or not?

Comment: Yes, indeed I am working on the problem with a version with integer values and a version with continuous values so my initial idea was juste to remove a precise value. Looking at : https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/mio.html#fixed-set-of-values , I found a solution by using the 9.13 equation and adding eps